# python sub process module reading and writing at the same time

Tags: python, file, subprocess, adb

I have to write "cat filename" to adb shell and read output from it using sub process module in python.
This is the code for the snippet:

```
import subprocess 
command = 'cat temp.txt\n'
p = subprocess.Popen("adb shell", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
b2 = str.encode(command) #to convert the command to byte
stdout = p.communicate(b2, timeout = 5)
print(stdout) #i am getting an error here. I need to store the output of the above file
```

Can someone let me know how to read data the from file using sub process module

Comment: Why not use Python builtins for IO operations? Is there a reason you *must* use subprocess?

Comment: better `text = open("temp.txt").read()` and later use `text` in `communicate`. Normally probably you would have to first use `Popen("cat temp.txt")` to get text from file. Using `communicate("cat temp.txt")` you probably send this string `cat temp.txt` instead of text from this file. BTW: And if you need to use in subprocess then maybe you could try to use directly `cat temp.txt | adb shell`

Comment: BTW you may need `shell=True` to run as string `"adb shell"` - `Popen("adb shell", ..., shell=True)` or you would have to use list `["adb", "shell"]` without `shell=True` - `Popen(["adb", "shell"], ...)`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you try to do `cat temp.txt | adb shell`

---

To use string `"adb shell"` instead of list `["adb", "shell"]` you need `shell=True`.

And if you use `shell=True` then:

you can pipe it directly

**BTW:** `communicate()` gives pair `(stdout, stderr)`

```
p = subprocess.Popen('cat temp.txt | adb shell', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(data)

if stdout:    
    print(stdout.decode())
if stderr:
    print(stderr.decode())
```

or you can assing file directly to `stdin`

```
p = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin=open('temp.txt'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(data)

if stdout:    
    print(stdout.decode())
if stderr:
    print(stderr.decode())
```

or you can read file in Python (at once in `bytes` mode `rb`) and send with `communicate()`

```
data = open('temp.txt', 'rb').read()

p = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(data)

if stdout:    
    print(stdout.decode())
if stderr:
    print(stderr.decode())
```

---

You can't use `communicate('cat temp.txt')` because it will not read text from file but it will send literally string `"cat temp.txt"`

---

**EDIT:** The same using two processes and `stdin=p1.stdout`

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('cat temp.txt', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)    
p2 = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p2.communicate()

if stdout:    
    print(stdout.decode())
if stderr:
    print(stderr.decode())
```

---

**BTW:**

Only first version (`'cat temp.txt | adb shell')` needs `shell=True`. Other versions can be done without `shell=True` but then you have to use lists `["cat", "temp.txt"]` and `["adb", "shell"]`

You may need `shell` also if you use `~` in path or you have to use Python to convert it to full path

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~/.bashrc')
```

and later `["cat", path]`